# Render partial with Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have the following code in the view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<soundyladder.Service.Models.Profile> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profile Login";
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml";
}
<style>
    #tableTest tr:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<div class="centering col-lg-6 logged_in_mainboxes">
    <h3>Profiles</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="tableTest" style="margin-top: 15px;">

            @foreach (var m in Model)
            {
                <tr>

                   <td>@Ajax.ActionLink(m.Name, "Edit", "ProfileLogin", null, new AjaxOptions()
                  {
                      HttpMethod = "Post",
                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                      UpdateTargetId = "result", // <-- DOM element ID to update
                       // <-- Replace the content of DOM element
                      // <-- HTTP method(Post/Get)
                  })</td>
                </tr>
            }

    </table>

    <div id="result">

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        return PartialView("_EditProfile");
    }
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="centering col-lg-6" style="padding: 0;">
                @Html.ActionLink("", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="body-content" style="margin-top: 40px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                @RenderBody()
                <div class="centering col-lg-6 footer" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 25px;">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div style="float: right; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-right: -15px;">
                        <img src="https://sdltridionworld.com/images/AppStore-Icon_tcm89-19881.png" width="100" height="35" />
                        <img src="https://portal.xsede.org/dashboard-portlet/images/playstore.png" width="90" height="35" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I have Is that when I hit the link, I am redirected to a new page, localhost:65148/ProfileLogin/Edit. I want the partial view to appear in the divbox, `result`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you load the script: @section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
} ?

Comment: @ZivWeissman: ofc. Im using unibtrusive In other places, and It works.

Comment: Oh then change actionresult to PartialViewResult

Comment: @ZivWeissman: It still don't work :/

Comment: can you post what is the anchor looks like after Rendered?

Comment: @ZivWeissman: <td><a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#result" href="/ProfileLogin/Edit">Blues ball</a></td>

Comment: I've run a test with this code, even with ActionResult and it works fine. What I can recommend: double check you load jQuery bundle and the unobtrusive-ajax (after jQuery). If you have all, post your html.

Comment: @ZivWeissman: Check my updated question.

Comment: Very strange. I've copy'ed your code, works fine to me. Double check web.config for Unobstrusive = true, and maybe stupid but you wrote Layout.cshtml while you use Layout2.cshtml?

Comment: Hehe, Im using Layout2.cshtml, so no wrong with that. I have  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />. I had the same problem with Ajax, so I deleted the projected, and downloaded It again from TFS, and It worked.